# Phpmailler Post Method Not Working

Tags: php, html, post

I have php website when try to submit contact form Post method not working. All of form elements inside of index.html i'll share the codes with you. I'll be happy if you could help me

In HTML File (index.php)

```
            <form id="main-contact-form"  method="post" action="sendemail.php">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"  placeholder="İsim Soyisim" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="mail_adress" class="form-control" placeholder="Mail Adresi" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Konu" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea  class="form-control" name="message" rows="8" placeholder="Mesaj" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">Mesaj Gönder</button>
            </form>
```

in PHP (sendemail.php)

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'xx@xxxxx.com';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxxx';               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->setFrom('xxx@xxxxxx.com', 'xx xx xx');     //Set who the message is to be sent from

$mail->addAddress('xxx@xxxxx.com', 'xx xx xx xx');  // Add a recipient
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body    = 'Mesaj Konusu'.$_POST['name'];
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body


if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   echo $_POST['subject'];
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';



 ?>
```

Thank You

Comment: You can’t usually expect PHP code to be parsed in `.html` files … rename your `index.html` to `index.php`

Comment: I did that but not worked

Comment: If your form action is `sendemail.php`, then your code to process the values (or to just make a debug output) of course belongs into that script. If you place it into the file that contains the HTML code of the form, but never actually send the form data to that script, then of course not POST values will be shown.

Comment: i got index.php  ( this is the main page of site )  and sendmail.php ( This contains only php codes from phpmailler send mail scripts). I corrected index.php and add php code in it. and form element outside of the php tags but i'll got empty result for the subject and other values.

Comment: So what does `print_r($_POST)` at the very beginning of your `sendmail.php` script get you?

Comment: i added that part to index page cause nothing passed to sendemail.php but it doesn't fix anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103743/discussion-between-kemal-ekren-and-cbroe).

Comment: It makes no sense that you try to add debug output of $_POST to a different script than the one that you are actually sending the data to.

Comment: so what can i do about it. I have form element and i need to send them to the php file that i'm gonna use for the send mail

Comment: Again, first of all you should check what data your sendmail.php script receives – so place the debug statement in there. Also make sure that you have PHP error_reporting enable and set to a value sensible for development.

Comment: I don't have any php error in the sendemail.php it worked fine. bu when insert to value ( which is the user typed in to input ) i see nothing in the mail. Just empty value.  Basicly it is contact form and i want to get users text in mail with sendemail.php

Comment: Well then perhaps the error lies in your code in sendmail.php

Comment: i 'll share of it too

Comment: I'll edit and share my all of codes

Comment: And a debug output of $_POST on top of that script gives what result exactly?

Comment: i got this. Array ( ) 1

Comment: That would mean your script did not receive any post data at all. Go look at the request that your browser makes in your browser’s developer tools, network panel. Is the request method actually POST? Does the server perhaps answer with a redirect (for whatever reason), so that the browser makes a second request, this time using GET?

Comment: Add a `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`, too – to check what method your script is actually requested with.

Comment: And what does the network panel show? Is it one request, directly made using GET (that would indicate an error in your HTML code for the form) – or a POST followed by a _second_ GET request (that would mean your server issues a redirect for some reason) …?

Comment: i says Request URL:http://www.domain.com/sendemail.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

Comment: It say somethin about jquery.js maybe that js conflict with POST method

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare with the === operador, to compare not only the same value, but also the same data type.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // …
}
```

Comment: That won’t change anything either. Both values are strings to begin with, so this condition won’t behave any differently.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer ajax prevent to POST method when i fix that everthings are became good

```
var form = $('#main-contact1-form');
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Mail Gönderiliyor...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Mesajınız başarı ile iletilmiştir. En kısa sürede tarafınıza dönüş yapılacaktır.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

when i delete this code everythings are good. How to fix that without delete it..? That's a new question to ask...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
function sendmail($to,$subject,$message,$from)
{
```

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()

```
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $from" . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $headers = "From: " . $from. "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

> you write ==POST(capital letters), and use method = post(small letters), so change it to small or capital in both places. or check sendmail.php

Comment: I don't follow you. in the both section name = small letter. You suggest to me change method write in capital letters

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` will always contain the uppercase version, PHP takes care of that.

Comment: method="POST"   try once and check